# Using little o to estimate maclaurin

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

The problem is to determine for what range of values of $\delta$ can we write

$$\ln(x+1)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{k-1} \frac{x^{k}}{k}+o(x^{\delta})$$
 as $x$ approaches zero.

It seems since $|R_{n}(x)|\leq\frac{x^{n}}{n}$ we can use the definition of "$o$" to try and satisfy $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{x^{n}}{n}}{x^{\delta}}=0$$
Which clearly works for all values of $\delta \in (-\infty,n)$
Is that correct? Or is the estimate of the remainder to harsh

Comment: You found that the error is $O(x^n)$. By the usual laws, this is $o(x^δ)$ for all $δ<n$. So yes, it is true. However, question the sensibility of negative values of $δ$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to derive that inequality.

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k
=\dfrac{1-x^n}{1-x}
$,
so
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^kx^k
=\dfrac{1-(-1)^nx^n}{1+x}
=\dfrac{1}{1+x}-\dfrac{(-1)^nx^n}{1+x}
$.

Integrating from $0$ to $t$,
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_0^t(-1)^kx^k dx
=\int_0^t\dfrac{1}{1+x}-(-1)^n\int_0^t\dfrac{x^ndx}{1+x}
$
or
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k\dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}
=\ln(1+t)-(-1)^n\int_0^t\dfrac{x^ndx}{1+x}
$
or
$\ln(1+t)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k\dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}
=(-1)^n\int_0^t\dfrac{x^ndx}{1+x}
$.

If $t > 0$ then
$\int_0^t\dfrac{x^ndx}{1+x}
\lt \int_0^tx^ndx
=\dfrac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}
$
and
$\int_0^t\dfrac{x^ndx}{1+x}
\gt \int_0^t\dfrac{x^ndx}{1+t}
=\dfrac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)(1+t)}
$.